# Magento - Display image instead of another if body has a specific class

Tags: image, class, magento

I need your help to do this with my Magento website.

In my header.phtml file I have this code that shows logo.

```
<img src='<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>' alt='<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>' />
```

This logo it's ok for all pages of the website, but I need to have another one logo (different colors) for the homepage. 
Homepage body has this specific class "cms-home" that maybe we can use to detect the page.

This is the url of the image I want to show: http://www.mydomain.it/skin/frontend/neighborhood/child/images/gm-home.png

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
<?php 
if(
Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  &&
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms'
) : ?>
<img src='http://www.mydomain.it/skin/frontend/neighborhood/child/images/gm-home.png' alt='<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>' />
<?php else:?>
<img src='<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>' alt='<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>' />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the header you can use `getIsHomePage` in a PHP if else statement to determine if the current page is the homepage or not:

```
 <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
      <img src='<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>' alt='<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>' />
 <?php else:?>
      <img src='<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>' alt='<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?>' />
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Just amend the src in the first to link to your alternative logo.